# Issues with Steam on Ubuntu 22.04 Using NVIDIA Driver 520

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam

Is anyone else experiencing issues with Steam? it seems to be the only application that struggles to run properly on anything other than driver version 470. I haven't found any issues with Steam in logs or using the `steam` command. I've uninstalled, purged, and reinstalled the driver a few times, even trying v515. I'd prefer not to go back to v470 since v520 has been tested now (Mentioned in Additional Drivers). My NVIDIA Server Settings are set to 'On Demand' since I'm running on a laptop so battery can be preserved when needed. There's plenty of questions already out there but are outdated or just don't work in my case. I'll keep testing different things, but I was hoping to get some extra information from the community.

NVIDIA Model: GTX 1650 4GB

CPU: Intel i5-10500H

I am however now able to get Steam Beta provided by flatpak running **once** or not at all in some cases

After some *further* testing it seems the Steam Beta can launch if I kill the background processes that are still running for some reason, I'll have to test if this works only on Steam Beta or regular Steam too

Comment: You may want to visit Steam support and see what they have to say.

Comment: Please [edit] and post your Nvidia model, at least. The latest driver version do NOT support all Nvidia chipsets, far from it, and many not so old cards only work with 470.

Comment: Check your PrefersNonDefaultGPU setting in /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop  This interacts with the power mode: Performance makes the high power GPU the default, Balanced does not.

Comment: @ubfan1 that was something I noticed, when I reinstall Steam at some point I'll give that a try, for now I have a solution that works for me

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution, and hopefully it should work for others:

1. Install Steam Beta
2. Create a custom `.desktop` entry and add the `flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam//beta` command

That should then kill the background processes when you exit!